# iTextSharp PdfStamper.PartialFormFlattening flattening only some, not all, of the fields

Tags: itext

The code below is correctly assigning the value "foo" to the named field, but the field is not being "flattened".   I must be neglecting a step, but I don't know what it is. Please advise. Thanks.

```
public byte[] FlattenSpecifiedFormFields(byte[] b, List<string> fieldNames2Flatten)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(b);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, ms);               
            foreach (string name in fieldNames2Flatten)
            {

                stamper.AcroFields.SetField(name, "foo");
                stamper.PartialFormFlattening(name);
            }

            stamper.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        };
    }
```

Comment: _After_ you get the `PdfStamper` instance, and **before** you call `PartialFormFlattening()` (outside the `foreach` block): `stamper.FormFlattening = true;`.

Comment: @kuujinbo Make that an answer so that the answer can be accepted and up-voted ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even when partially flattening a form, the `PdfStamper` `FormFlattening` property *must* be set to `true`. I.e.:

```
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
stamper.FormFlattening = true;

foreach (string name in fieldNames2Flatten)
{
    stamper.AcroFields.SetField(name, "foo");
    stamper.PartialFormFlattening(name);
}
```

Comment: This code generates an internal null reference exception for me and I can't figure out why. Not sure if it is because the document is containing signatures...